# How to array data from @foreach in Laravel Views

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, laravel-5.3

I know this is possible but  I've tried to search from the net but I've never found an answer so if anyone who knows how to push data to array from @foreach using Laravel View please help me. Thanks in advance

## Here is the code

```
@foreach ($fields as $key => $rel)

 {{ $arrayData = array(

    'field_type' =>'$rel->field_type'
 )}}

@endforeach
```

## The error I've receiving is

ErrorException in helpers.php line 519:
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\fields.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quote from $rel->field_type

```
@foreach ($fields as $key => $rel)

 {{ $arrayData = array(

    'field_type' =>$rel->field_type
 )}}

@endforeach
```

Comment: Error sir  a Use of undefined constant field_type - assumed 'field_type' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\papers\resources\views\admin\fields.blade.php)

Comment: can you print print_r($fields) before foreach loop and update question.i think field_type not there in array

Comment: {
  "field_id": 82,
  "field_name": "field_name",
  "field_slug": "field_slug",
  "field_label": "field_label",
  "field_type": "text", }

Comment: @Paul.can you post all data  of printed print_r($fields) becasue that data is not array

Comment: ooops my fault lemme send the image for the output

Comment: [{"field_id":82,"field_name":"field_name","field_slug":"field_slug","field_label":"field_label","field_type":"text","field_attributes":"{\"default_value\":null,\"attributes\":{\"required\":\"required\"}}","field_parent":28,"if_condition":"","if_so":"","sort_order":1,"form_id":28,"section_id":1}]